# C# class properties enumerable

Tags: c#, wpf, enumeration

I have a problem with enumeration of a class. I searched all over the internet and Stackoverflow, but I'm afraid my limited experience with C# limits me from recognizing the exact situation and the solution. The code I have:

```
public List<annotation> annotations = new List<annotation>();

public class annotation
{
    public annotation(int pos, int x2, int y2, string artnr)
    {
        this.ArtNr = artnr;
        this.Pos = pos;
        this.X2 = x2;
        this.Y2 = y2;
    }
    public string ArtNr;
    public int Pos;
    public int X2;
    public int Y2;


}

public void add_Anno(string artnr, int x2, int y2)
{
    annotations.Add(new annotation(0,x2,y2,artnr));
}
```

After adding sever annotations I want to display them in a WPF Canvas object. Problem is I can't loop through all items in the list. My question is which method should I use for enumeration and how to apply it? The list contains both integers and a string. I tried to use:

```
System.Collections.IEnumerator ie = annotations.GetEnumerator();
while(ie.MoveNext())
{
    annotation test = ie.GetType().GetProperties();
}
```

Meanwhile I'm looking at reflection in "Microsoft Press Exam 7--483" to see if this is a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply need to use `foreach`, it will iterate each one of your elements in the list. There's no need to use reflection:

```
foreach (var annotation in annotations)
{
    int position = annotation.Pos;
    string atrNr = annotation.ArtNr;
}
```

As a side-note, I would advise you to look at the [C# Naming Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx), and perhaps study about [Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)

A quick refactoring would look like this:

```
public class Annotation
{
    public Annotation(int pos, int x2, int y2, string artNr)
    {
        this.ArtNr = artNr;
        this.Pos = pos;
        this.X2 = x2;
        this.Y2 = y2;
    }

    public string ArtNr { get; private set; }
    public int Pos { get; private set; }
    public int X2 { get; private set; }
    public int Y2 { get; private set; }
}
```

If you're using C# 6, you can drop the `private set`.

Comment: Thanks, first I had an Enumerable error, but it seems adding enum was not necessary at all.